# Error 401 : Unauthorized

Tags: rust

i'm using getLatestBlockhash in my code, and i keep getting this error ,,Error: failed to get recent blockhash: Error: 401 Unauthorized: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"d528a90a-0674-437d-965e-12650f8e6456","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Must be authenticated!"}}"

I'm using an RPC from hellomoon that does support wws.

Anyone know what the problem can be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/error-on-connection-confirmtransaction-ws-error

You can try some other service like Helius,Quicknode, Alchemy or Shyft for RPCs as well, all have free tier.

Comment: Please feel free to vote to close when there's a duplicate!